# Session ID not preserved between page navigation using Puppeteer's .goto method?

Tags: puppeteer

When attempting to navigate to a sub-page using Puppeteer's `goto` method, I have noted that cookie information is not being correctly preserved between navigation.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://www.example.com/Summary.aspx?sid=100-013-030);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example1.png'});
  await page.goto('http://www.example.com/DetailInfo.aspx?did=af902cb3');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example2.png'});
  await browser.close();
});
```

In the code above, upon making the second `goto` call, the `example2.png` file generated is a screenshot of the Summary landing page; indicating a silent failure. Conversely, when navigating manually within the Chrome browser itself, copying and pasting the `DetailInfo` link into a new tab opens the intended page with no issue.

Upon further investigation, I did note that the website is keeping a cookie with a session ID in the browser cache, but what is the difference between the manual approach, and using Puppeteer that is creating this discrepancy?

Comment: ASP pages are harder to deal with because they store tons of state in the client and on the server, then expect you to only use their controls to navigate (i.e. only click on their links or buttons, never go to pages directly).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Aankhen, that definitely sounds like it might be the root cause in relation to what I'm experiencing. I figured that using Chrome Headless with Puppeteer was the answer, though. Pasting direct links works in the browser when done manually, but when attempting to emulate this behaviour with Puppeteer, something seem to be getting lost.

Comment: Is it possible to share the URLs? Perhaps we could isolate the behaviour.